# Is it good practice to just test that components don't throw?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

This might be a ridiculous question, but I'm just learning testing and wondering if the following test, repeated throughout a react native app, would actually be worth implementing. I'm using jest with react native testing library.

```
it('renders properly', () => {
  const component = render(<SomeScreen />)
  expect(component).not.toThrow()
})
```

Where `<SomeScreen />` is a screen in the app... It is not supposed to throw... This would not be shallowly rendered so most of the children would be included, though some things will be mocked where necessary.

If this is implemented to run on every pull request, would this actually provide any value?

Is something like this considered good/bad practice? It seems too simple, but is essentially what I've been asked to do.

Comment: If it _did_ throw on rendering, the assertion wouldn't actually be be reached. Stuff like this tends to just be a placeholder to show you where a test should go, it has no value itself.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can write tests like this but it does not really add any value.
Ideally you should be testing your logic inside the component. For instance if SomeScreen is supposed to render a text element that contains some heading then you should be testing that whether that text element is present on the screen or not when you render this  component.

```
it('renders properly', () => {
  const component = render(<SomeScreen />)
  expect(component).not.toThrow()
})
```

The above test becomes useless as when you tested your logic for the text element, your SomeScreen would have rendered successfully, so no need to separately check if it threw any error while rendering.